# Running a case-insensitive cypher query

Tags: neo4j, case-insensitive, cypher

Is it possible to run a case-insensitive cypher query on neo4j?

Try that: http://console.neo4j.org/

When I type into this:

```
start n=node(*) 
match n-[]->m 
where (m.name="Neo") 
return m
```

it returns one row. But when I type into this:

```
start n=node(*) 
match n-[]->m 
where (m.name="neo") 
return m
```

it does not return anything; because the name is saved as "Neo". Is there a simple way to run case-insensitive queries?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, by using case insensitive regular expressions:

```
WHERE m.name =~ '(?i)neo'
```

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#case-insensitive-regular-expressions

Comment: =~ operator does not use Indexes

Comment: how can I pass parameter here? `'(?i)$param'` and `'(?!)'+$param` doesn't work

Comment: I think you have to use the entire regex string as the parameter.

Answer (score 10):

Another way would be:

```
WHERE LOWER(m.Name) = LOWER("Neo")
```

And if you are using the Neo4j Client (.NET):

```
Client.Cypher.Match("(m:Entity)")
    .Where("LOWER(m.Name) = LOWER({name})")
    .WithParam("name", inputName)
    .Return(m => m.As<Entity>())
    .Results
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This solution is easier to apply for parameter

Comment: @rotgers Wouldn't using the LOWER() function affect index lookups defined on the actual string?

Comment: @Partha, no idea, I haven't touched Neo4j for over a year.

Comment: FYI - LOWER() has been replaced with toLower().  

[Doc link for string operators](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/string/#functions-tolower)

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is looking on how to do this with a parameter, I managed to do it like this.

```
query = "{}{}{}".format('Match (n) WHERE n.pageName =~ "'"(?i)", name, '" RETURN n')
```

and "name" is the variable or your parameter

Comment: Can you explain how this works, or even how to read it?

Comment: `"{}{}{}"` looks like placeholders and `.format` is going to take in arguments in order or replacing placeholders.  Readability is definitely one issue here but the larger issue seems to be this is just string concatenation not parametrisation. So in I could just do this   `$"Match (n) WHERE n.pageName =~ {(?i)} name RETURN n` (C# string interpolation)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter to the case insensitive regular expression like:

**WHERE m.name =~'(?i)({param})**