# Neo4j - incasesensitive lucene query

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

I am doing suggestions from Neo4j database with cypher query, through a php library. My concern is that it gives suggestion slowly. I noticed that if i use lucene query in index lookup the query runs faster, but i did not find any method that does incasesensitive search.
The query would look something like this:

```
START n = node:Destination('name:*term*')
...
```

but this is case sensitive. So if the value stored in db is for example "Term" i wont get any results.
Is there any way that i can do case insensitive search?

Comment: this one was answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439278/running-a-case-insensitive-cypher-query/13439470

Comment: If you configure your index to be a fulltext-index it is case insensitive. See: * [Configure Lucene indexes to be case insensitive](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-create-advanced.html)
* [Create Indexes with configuration over the REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-create-node-index-with-configuration)